# Is it possible to make a dataframe that only contains one row of a csv at a time?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to make bar graphs for each row in a csv file that I have. I have no problem making bar graphs for each row all in one go, but I want to make a png file out of each bar chart, so it would be very convenient to fill the dataframe with one row at a time.

This is a snippet of code that I have that makes the bar graphs all at once from my CSV file:

```
df2 = df.set_index('ID').T
df2.plot(kind='bar', subplots=True, layout=(2,2), legend=False, color='g')
plt.show()
```

This produces bar graphs for each row, but I want to be able to separate them and make an image file for each graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through each row, convert it to a DataFrame and create a bar chart for that row

```
#Iterate through each row
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   
    #Convert row to dataframe
    df_row = row.to_frame().T

    #Proceed as before
    df2 = df_row.set_index('ID').T
    df2.plot(kind='bar', subplots=True, layout=(2,2), legend=False, color='g')
```